# apt-mirror -error?

Tags: apt, apt-mirror

I have successfully set up an Ubuntu repository for 14.04 locally using `apt-mirror`.

But at the first in the `sources.list` I have given `deb-amd64` to download 64-bit repository and after completing it I just added another set of deb repositories (say `deb-i386`) for downloading 32-bit.

I stopped it in the middle way because I don’t wish to mirror 32-bit repositories. After that I ran `clean.sh` and that removed 32-bit files.

Now when I give `sudo apt-get update` while using LAN repositories it gets successfully updates and in between it shows error that it cannot fetch binary `i386` files. Error as follows:

```
Err http://<lanip> trusty/main i386 Packages
  404  Not Found
Err http://<lanip> trusty/restricted i386 Packages
  404  Not Found
W: Failed to fetch http://<lanip>/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://<lanip>/ubuntu/dists/trusty/restricted/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://<lanip>/ubuntu/dists/trusty/universe/binary-i386/
```

my apt-mirror list is as follows :

```
  ############# config ##################


set base_path    /data/ubuntu_repository/trusty_repo
  set nthreads     20

  set _tilde 0
    #
    #################################

# Trusty 64Bit Mirror
deb-amd64 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main restricted universe multiverse
deb-amd64 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb-amd64 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb-amd64 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-proposed main restricted universe multiverse
deb-amd64 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-backports main restricted universe multiverse

###### Ubuntu Partner Repo
deb-amd64 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu trusty partner

###### Ubuntu Extras Repo
deb-amd64 http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main

clean http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu
clean http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu
clean http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu
```

Comment: post the contents of your `/etc/apt/sources.list` file

Comment: deb http://192.168.1.50/ubuntu/ trusty main restricted universe multiverse 

###### Ubuntu Update Repos
deb http://192.168.1.50/ubuntu/ trusty-security main restricted universe multiverse 
deb http://192.168.1.50/ubuntu/ trusty-updates main restricted universe multiverse 
deb http://192.168.1.50/ubuntu/ trusty-proposed main restricted universe multiverse 
deb http://192.168.1.50/ubuntu/ trusty-backports main restricted universe multiverse

Comment: apt-mirror list as follows :

Comment: post it in your question.

Comment: You say you do not want to mirror i386, and removed all of the i386 files, so why are you surprised that apt-get on an i386 system fails to fetch an i386 Packages file?

Comment: I am surprised , bcoz in my 64 bit system showing an error in fetching 32 bit binary isn't making any sense. If it shows an error in fetching 64 is reasonable.

Comment: I strongly believe that , when I have 32 given  bit packages to download , it will get written to Packages.gz so why when I give sudo apt-get update will read the list and shows cant fetch 32 bit files. So I may need to replace Packages.gz in each of the folders . I think so but I am not sure of it. if its so then How I can do sudo dpkg-scanpackages recursively to remake it . Please any one help me solve my real issue.

Answer (score 2):

I had the exact issue; my amd64-only mirror was working but I *hated* those errors. The solution was to add `[ arch=amd64 ]` in each active line of my `sources.list` file.

No more errors! And where did I find this information, you ask? >blush< by pointing the **RTFM** finger at myself. `$ man sources.list`

```
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 14.04 LTS _Trusty Tahr_ - Release amd64 (20140417)]/ trusty main restricted

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
#deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main restricted
deb [ arch=amd64 ] http://local_apt_mirror/ubuntu/ trusty main restricted
#deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main restricted
deb-src [ arch=amd64 ] http://local_apt_mirror/ubuntu/ trusty main restricted
```